# Scala: Divide by zero

Tags: scala, divide-by-zero

I have something like this in my app:

```
def something(x: Int, y: Int) Z {

    (x / y)
}
```

Now, if the someval is not a number (meaning that either x or y is equal to 0), then I'd like Z to just become 0 instead of displaying an error (`[ArithmeticException: Division by zero]`)

I know I can do:

```
Try(someVale) orElse Try(0)
```

However, that'll give me `Success(0)` whereas I'd just like for it to give me a `0` in that case.

Maybe there's something like `if ArithmeticException then 0` in Scala or something to remove the "Success" and parenthesis. Can someone shed some light please?

Comment: Just in case: is it just an example of unavoidable exception or the problem is literally in "divide by zero"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm assuming "divide by zero" is just an example and you can't avoid throwing an exception. When you can avoid throwing an exception you should do it like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21125705/406435).

You could use `getOrElse` method on `Try` instead of `orElse`:

```
def something(x: Int, y: Int) = Try(x/y).getOrElse(0)
```

In case you want to recover only on `ArithmeticException` you could use `recover` method and `get`:

```
def something(x: Int, y: Int) =
  Try(x/y).recover{ case _: ArithmeticException => 0 }.get
```

With method `get` you'll get an exception if `Try` is `Failure`, but `recover` allows you to convert `Failure` to `Success`.

You could also convert your `Try` to `Option` to return "no result" without showing exception:

```
def something(x: Int, y: Int): Option[Int] = Try(x/y).toOption
```

Answer (score 15):

I think I would look to :

```
def something(x: Int, y:Int) = if ( y != 0) x/y else 0
```

Comment: +1 - This is the only reasonable answer.  Catching an arithmetic exception with lots of extra machinery and huge runtime cost instead of executing a single simple conditional is madness!

Comment: that depends on how often y==0; if y == 0 is rare then typically try-catch is free whereas if(y != 0) has constant cost in all cases.

Answer (score 4):

Just catch the exception and return 0 is the simplest way.

```
def something(x: Int, y: Int) = try {
    (x / y)
  } catch {
    case ae: java.lang.ArithmeticException => 0
  }
```

Run it:

```
scala> something(1,0)
res0: Int = 0

scala> something(2,1)
res1: Int = 2
```

Comment: Since `ae` is unused, `case _: Arithm...`  I'd also lose the outer braces and the parens...